# Getting IllegalStateException when calling sendTextMessage

Tags: java, android, sms

I've been trying to send an SMS from my app on Android Studio, but I keep getting a runtime error:

```
Unfortunately, your App has stopped working
```

each time I press the button.

Here is the code:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message){
    PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(DisplayMessageActivity.this, 0, new Intent(sent), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, piSent, null);
}
```

When debugging, it is going over all the statements except for the last one, involving the `sendTextMessage` function.

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3758)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4377)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18044)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3753)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4377)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18044)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10103 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
            at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:901)
            at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:278)
            at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:146)
            at com.example.georges.mobilenetworking.DisplayMessageActivity.sendSMS(DisplayMessageActivity.java:159)
            at com.example.georges.mobilenetworking.DisplayMessageActivity.SMS(DisplayMessageActivity.java:75)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3753)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4377)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18044)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I added the permission needed, please check the Manifest File below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.georges.mobilenetworking" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.send_sms"/>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainScreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.georges.mobilenetworking.MainScreen" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ConnectivityActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_connectivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".DisplayMessageActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.georges.mobilenetworking.DisplayMessageActivity" />
        </activity>`
        <activity
            android:name=".Wifi_P2P.Wifi_P2P"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_wifi__p2_p"
            android:parentActivityName=".DisplayMessageActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.georges.mobilenetworking.Wifi_P2P.WifiP2P" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Note: When I use the same code on another PC, it works perfectly.

Comment: Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>` permission

Comment: The answer is given in the logs - *Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10103 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's written in the logs that the error is specifically due to permission not provided to send SMS.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10103 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
```

All you need to do is to add permission in your manifest like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

**EDIT:**

**SEND_SMS** not **send_sms**.SEND_SMS should be in caps.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes that can also be the issue.I only said that it could be the issue and if so can be solved by this approach.Also OP didn't mention about declining permission to application on device.

Comment: I added the permission before writing the function.. This isn't the solution, note my phone software version is Jelly Beans

Answer (score 4):

As you can see the issue is arising  because of security permission. Can you check if the version of your Android is **Marshmallow**.

This version need exclusive permission while using any feature of the Android.

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html) for more information.

Also as per the suggestion by @Anuridh Sharma check your manifest file if it contains permission for sending sms for android version lower/equals to **Lollipop**

Update below line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.**send_sms**"/>
```

with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.**SEND_SMS**" />
```

Comment: the permission was included from the very beginning.. I didnt forget. Note, my phone is running Jelly Beans as software version

Comment: If thats the case, then check if this permission node is a direct child of your  application node in the manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

You should add the required permission to send message "android.permission.SEND_SMS"

Add the following line just above the application tag in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Hope this will help for you.

Comment: I included the permission at first...so this is not helping me. Note my phone version is Jelly Beans

Comment: Are you sure you added the permission at proper place. If yes means check the logcat and verify you are getting the same error.

Comment: change android.permission.send_sms to android.permission.SEND_SMS